# Cayley Graphs of Product groups is product of Cayley Graphs

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, graph-theory

Let us have two Groups $G$ and $H$. Then, is the [Cayley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph) graph associated with $G\times H$, the direct product of the groups with respect to some generating set with cardinality $mn$;  a product of the Cayley graphs associated to groups $G$ and $H$ with generating sets of cardinalities $m$ and $n$ respectively? If so, is the graph product a cartesian product?

I think yes, because the product group acts transitively on the product of Cayley graphs, I think? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: just write out the definitions...

Comment: @mathworker21 you mean, the answer is yes? But, what would be the generating set of the new graph?

Comment: I just assumed your question would be easy. Now I read your question and am confused. First of all, how do you intersect two arbitrary groups? Second, you use the word "is" too many times in the first question. Third, what is the Cayley graph associated with a group? You need a generating set...

Comment: @mathworker21 edited the question. Look into it now

Comment: @mathworker21 the wikipedia link answers my question. But, a more thorough proof is what I want

Comment: I still don't know how to associate a Cayley graph to a group.

Comment: @mathworker21 you may see the wikipedia link I gave in the question

Comment: I've already clearly said that you also need a generating set.

Comment: @vidyarthi mathworker21 is correct, a Cayley graph needs two inputs, a group and a subset of that group, usually called the connection set. (Some people would ask that this set be a generating set.) In your question, you say "THE Cayley graph associated with $G\times H$", but unless you tell us what connection set you have in mind, the question is ill-posed.

Comment: @verret slightly modified the question. by the way, are you in some downvoting spree?

Comment: @vidyarthi This version is even more confused than the previous one. Rather than doing random edits until you hit something meaningful, my suggestion would be to actually work out some small examples, to build up your intuition. For example, find all the Cayley graphs of a cyclic group of 2, then all the Cayley graphs of a cyclic group of order 3, and then all the Cayley graphs of their direct products. See which ones are Cartesian products, which ones are not, etc...

Comment: @verret What was wrong with my answer?

Comment: @MikeEarnest Your answer made it seem like an arbitrary Cayley graph on a direct product of groups is a Cartesian product, which is not true. (See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324990/are-all-even-regular-undirected-cayley-graphs-of-class-1#comment839652_324990 where it was quoted in this way.)

Granted, the fault was at least partly in the question itself, which was written confusingly, but when a question is confused, it's better to get the author to clarify, rather than answer it, which can make things even more confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ and $H$ be groups, with generating sets $S$ and $T$. Then $(S\times \{e_H\})\cup (\{e_G\}\times T)$ is a generating set for $G\times H$. Moreover, using Wikipedia's notation,
$$
\Gamma(G\times H, (S\times \{e_H\})\cup (\{e_G\}\times T))\cong \Gamma(G,S)\times \Gamma(H,T)
$$
where the rightmost $\times$ is a Cartesian product. This is because the Cayley graph for $G\times H$ has an edge of the form $(g,h)\to (gs,h)$ and $(g,h)\to (g,ht)$, which exactly fits the definition of the Cartesian product of $\Gamma(G,S)$ and $\Gamma(H,T)$.

It may help to look at some examples, like $(G,S)=(H,T)=(\mathbb Z_2,\{1\})$, where the generating set for $G\times H=\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$ is $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$.

Comment: suppose I know the generating set of $G\times H$. Can we split it into the generating sets respectively of $G$ and $H$. Like, for example, $G\times H=\mathbb{Z}_{14}$, with the set $\{1,2,12,13\}$. Then what are the generating sets for $G$, $H$ . The elements in the generating set can be written as $\{(1,1),(0,2),(0,5),(1,6)\}$ where the elements in pairs  are taken from $(\mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_7)$. So, how do we split them?