# Cayley graphs of product of groups

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, cayley-graphs

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3064867/cayley-graphs-of-product-groups-is-product-of-cayley-graphs) question, we have that the Cayley graph of direct product of two groups is a cartesian product of some cayley graphs on the factor groups. But, I do not see this translation easily.

Specifically, let us say I take the group $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_8$ and the cycle graph on it. The cycle graph can be written as a cayley graph by taking any non-involution element and its inverse as the generating set in the group $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_8$. But, how is it a cartesian product of some graphs on the indivdual groups $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_8$? Is the ususal definition of cayley graphs not used while making the product graph? That is, can the cycle on the product group elements be written as a cartesian product of two $1$-factors on the individual factor group elements?  Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/8$ cannot be generated by only one element (it isn't cyclic). So if you take the "cycle graph" as you've defined it, you will not get a cayley graph at all.

Comment: If instead you take the cayley graph with two generators (one generator of $\mathbb{Z}/8$ and one of $\mathbb{Z}/2$) then you'll find you _do_ get the product graph of the respective cayley graphs

Comment: @HallaSurvivor thanks! just post these as answer and I would accept it!

Comment: Contrary to what you claim, the Cayley graph of a direct product of two groups is NOT necessarily a Cartesian product of Cayley graphs on the factor groups. This has been pointed out to you multiple times, on MO and at the question you are currently citing. Yet you continue to cite this as a fact...

Comment: @verret yes,  that is why I asked this question. But, the answer shows this is true, at least symbolically. By the way, why dont you explicitly post a detailed example that shows your claim. The example you said in a prior comment was confusing to me, and you thought that I understood your claim. I am still not a thorough expert like you, so please expand your example you gave at my previous question...

Comment: contd.. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3064867/cayley-graphs-of-product-groups-is-product-of-cayley-graphs). There, you mention to take cayley graphs of cyclic group of prime orders for small primes and then see which are cayley and which are not. But, this question which I ask here is regarding that clarification, so you could answer that here explicitly, instead of assuming I understand things as quickly as you would! and by the way, my claim stems from the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph#Examples)

Comment: No, neither the answer you link to, nor the Wikipedia page show that what you say is true. You are misunderstanding both claims. They both say that a $\bf{particular}$ Cayley graph on a direct product is a Cartesian product of Cayley graphs on the factors. On Wikipedia, that is what the remark "(with the cartesian product of generating sets as a generating set)" means, for example. Neither of them claims that an $\bf{arbitrary}$ Cayley graph on a direct product is a Cartesian product.

Comment: I've already given you counterexamples with explanations many times, for example here :
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324990/are-all-even-regular-undirected-cayley-graphs-of-class-1
I think you could clarify this for yourself by actually looking at small examples like I suggested many time, but you seem to be unwilling to do this and prefer to repeat the wrong claim. Still, I wanted to record that the first claim of your post is wrong, to help anybody else reading it.

Comment: @verret thanks, got it. But, I think the cayley graphs which can be written as a cartesian products of cayley graphs on factor subgroups is dense in the set of all cayley graphs on the group with repsect to some generating set

Comment: @vidyarthi I don't even know what "dense" means in this context, but it doesn't sound right at all.
If $G=H\times K$, then the number of Cayley (di)graphs on $G$ is roughly $2^{|G|}=2^{|H||K|}$, of which only at most $2^{|H||}2^{|K|}=2^{|H|+|K|}$ arise naturally as Cartesian products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/8$ is not cyclic, so it needs at least $2$ generators to get the whole group. So if you take the "cycle graph" as you've defined it, you will not get a cayley graph at all.

If instead you take the cayley graph with two generators (one of $\mathbb{Z}/8$ and one of $\mathbb{Z}/2$) you'll find you *do* get the product of the respective cayley graphs.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: thanks! so then studying graphs corresponding to simple groups will surely help us in the study of graphs on all groups right?

Comment: Possibly! Geometric group theory tends to be a rather coarse tool. In particular, most geometric group theorertic techniques can't distinguish _any_ finite group from the trivial one! I'm not sure how simple groups play into the classification of infinite groups, but they certainly _sound_ like something that would be of interest! It's a good idea, but unfortunately I'm not enough of a specialist to say for sure